# Toolbar item for delete - for 2sxc module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I create [2sxc.org](http://2sxc.org/) app for [DNN](http://www.dnnsoftware.com) and don't know how to allow a user to delete the content item?

Is there some toolbar snippet like:

```
@Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,replace")
```

But also to create delete button?

If there is no such command, how can be manually created? Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full list of actions is listed here

https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/blob/master/src/inpage/2sxc._actions.js

So just use

```
@Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,replace,remove");
```

The reason is that delete is not implemented yet, as it has some complex & far reaching consequences. So the current button only removes it.

Comment: Is there some way to add custom button?

Answer (score 0):

Update: 2sxc 8.6 beta is out, and it supports adding custom buttons to the toolbar. Read about the API, JSON definitions in the wiki. I'll try to blog about specific step-by-step in a few weeks...

Note that delete has some complex issues explained here: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/618